# A combinatorial question with an easy rolling dice game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, factorial

Recently, I had played a dice game with my classmates. The game is like that:

> Find a person rolls a dice and got a number $X$, then he rolls it again. If he gets $X$ again, the game stops; if he gets another number $Y$, he rolls it again. He rolls the dice again and again until the number has appeared before.

Then, I thought of a question: What is the probability of rolling the dice with $F$ faces $N$ times and stop when he rolls again $\left(F\ge N>0\right)$? Let $P\left(X\right)$ be the probability of rolling the dice $X$ times and stop when he rolls again. Then, $$P\left(N\right)=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{F}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{F}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{3}{F}\right)\cdots\left(1-\dfrac{N}{F}\right)\dfrac{N}{F}=\dfrac{N\left(F!\right)}{F^{N+1}\left(F-N-1\right)!}$$

Obviously, $P\left(1\right)+P\left(2\right)+\cdots+P\left(F\right)=1$. You can prove it by the probability. However, I want to find an algebraic way to solve it. but it is hard because of the complicated expression. Is there any ways can I solve it? Also, I want to find the expected value of $P\left(N\right)$, which means I need to find the sum $\sum_{k=0}^F kP\left(k\right)$. Is there any closed form? Please answer. Thank you!

Comment: notice that $P(N)$ satisfies the recurrence relation: $$ F n y(n+1)-(n+1) (F-n-1) y(n)=0,y(-2)=-\frac{2 F F!}{(F+1)!},y(-1)=-1,y(0)=0,y(1)=\frac{F!}{F^2 (F-2)!} $$. Take a try with generating functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i would do to model the situation. Since typing matrices with dots is a problem for me, i will type matrices in the special case $F=7$, seven faces. The game is modeled by the Markov chain with states $\boxed 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$. Here $0$ is "final", absorbant, a no escape state. All other states $k$ have the meaning of "already $k$ different face numbers were seen", and the game starts after the first rolling and seeing the first number, so $1$ is initial. The picture of the states is:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
1 @>{1-\frac17}>>
2 @>{1-\frac27}>>
3 @>{1-\frac37}>>
4 @>{1-\frac47}>>
5 @>{1-\frac57}>>
6 @>{1-\frac67}>>
7
\\
@V {\frac 17} V V
@V {\frac 27} V V
@V {\frac 37} V V
@V {\frac 47} V V
@V {\frac 57} V V
@V {\frac 67} V V
@V {\frac 77} V V
\\
0 @=
0 @=
0 @=
0 @=
0 @=
0 @=
0 @>1>> 0
\end{CD}

The transition matrix is
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&
\\
\frac 17 & 0 & \frac 67
\\
\frac 27 & & 0 & \frac 57
\\
\frac 37 & & & 0 & \frac 47
\\
\frac 47 & & & & 0 & \frac 37
\\
\frac 57 & & & & & 0 & \frac 27
\\
\frac 67 & & & & & & 0 & \frac 17
\\
\frac 77 & & & & & & & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
= T
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1&
\\
 & 0 & 1
\\
 & & 0 & 1
\\
 & & & 0 & 1
\\
 & & & & 0 & 1
\\
 & & & & & 0 & 1
\\
 & & & & & & 0 & 1
\\
 & & & & & & & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
}_{=:\Lambda\text{ Jordan matrix to eigenvalues }1;0,0,\dots,0}
T^{-1}
\ ,\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ where the base change matrix is}
\\
T&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1&\frac{6!}{7^6}\\
1&&\frac{5!}{7^5}\\
1&&&\frac{4!}{7^4}\\
1&&&&\frac{3!}{7^3}\\
1&&&&&\frac{2!}{7^2}\\
1&&&&&&\frac{1!}{7^1}\\
1&&&&&&&\frac{0!}{7^0}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1&t_1\\
1&&t_2\\
1&&&t_3\\
1&&&&t_4\\
1&&&&&t_5\\
1&&&&&&t_6\\
1&&&&&&&t_7\\
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The labels for the rows and columns are $0,1,2,\dots,F$. Above $F=7$, but please write in mind the general matrices instead.

The diagonal entry $t_k$ in $T$, $1\le k\le F$, is 
$$ \color{blue}{t_k=\frac{(F-k)!}{F^{F-k}}}\ .$$

The inverse of $T$, the matrix $T^{-1}$, has the same positions for non-zero elements as $T$, diagonally we have the inverse values, and the first column is $1;-1/t_1,-1/t_2,\dots,-1/t_F$.

Let $p(k)$ be the probability to follow the path $1\to 2\dots\to k\to 0$. In words, last (non-final) state is $k$ and/or we reach the final state after *exactly* $k$ steps.

Then the entry in the position $(1,0)$ of $A^k$ is the probability to reach the final state in *at most* $k$ steps. So to get *exactly* $k$ steps we look at the $(1.0)$ entry of $(A^k-A^{k-1})$.

So the probabilities
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(1) &= \frac 1F\ ,\\
p(2) &= \left(1-\frac 1F\right)\frac 2F\ ,\\
p(3) &= \left(1-\frac 1F\right)\left(1-\frac 2F\right)\frac 3F\ ,\\
&\vdots\vdots\vdots\vdots\vdots\\
&\vdots\vdots\vdots\vdots\vdots \text{ and so on till}\\
&\vdots\vdots\vdots\vdots\vdots\\
p(F-1) &= \left(1-\frac 1F\right)
\left(1-\frac 2F\right)
\dots
\left(1-\frac {F-2}F\right)
\frac {F-1}F
\ ,\\
p(F) &= \left(1-\frac 1F\right)
\left(1-\frac 2F\right)
\dots
\left(1-\frac {F-2}F\right)
\left(1-\frac {F-1}F\right)\frac FF
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
(written here explicitly, please compare with the posted formulas,) can be also obtained by building $\Lambda^k-\Lambda^{k-1}$, followed by conjugation with $T$ to obtain $T(\Lambda^k-\Lambda^{k-1})T^{-1}$, followed by looking into the $(1,0)$ entry. Doing this, we obtain for $p(k)$ the product of the row vector with entries $0;0,\dots,0,-t_k,t_k,0,\dots$ (with $-t_k$ in the column with label $k$, and $t_k$ in the column with label $(k+1)$, if this column still exists), and the column vector with entries $1;-1/t_1, -1/t_2, \dots$, i.e

> $$
> p(k) = t_1\left(\frac 1{t_k}-\frac 1{t_{k+1}}\right)
> =
> \frac{(F-1)!}{F^{F-1}}
> \left(
>  \frac{F^{F-k}}{(F-k)!}
>  -
>  \frac{F^{F-k-1}}{(F-k-1)!}
> \right)
> \ ,\ 
> 1\le k< F
> \ .
> $$

This is not so important per se. (Since we already know a simple formula for $p(k)$.) 
But we can use it, or equivalently the Jordan decomposition (and type more, but type structurally) to compute the sum
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{1\le k\le F}k\; p(k)
&=
p(1)+2p(2)+\dots+Fp(F)
\\
&=\text{Entry $(1,0)$ in }T\Big(\ 
 (\Lambda^1-\Lambda^0)
+2(\Lambda^2-\Lambda^1)
+3(\Lambda^3-\Lambda^2)+\dots
+F(\Lambda^F-\Lambda^{F-1})\ \Big)T^{-1}
\\
&=\text{Entry $(1,0)$ in }
T
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0 & -1 &-1 & -1 &\dots & -1\\
0 &    &-1 & -1 &\dots & -1\\
0 &    &   & -1 &\dots & -1\\
\vdots & & & &\ddots &\vdots\\
0 &    &   &  &  & -1
\end{bmatrix}
T^{-1}
\\
&=\text{Entry $(1,0)$ in }
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0 & -t_1 &-t_1 & -t_1 &\dots & -t_1\\
0 &    &-t_2 & -t_2 &\dots & -t_2\\
0 &    &   & -t_3 &\dots & -t_3\\
\vdots & & & &\ddots &\vdots\\
0 &    &   &  &  & -t_F
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &\\
-1/t_1 &1/t_1\\
-1/t_2 &&1/t_2\\
-1/t_3 &&&1/t_3\\
\vdots & & & &\ddots \\
-1/t_F &&&&&1/t_F\\
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&=t_1\left(\frac 1{t_1}+\frac 1{t_2}+\frac 1{t_3}+\dots+\frac 1{t_F}\right)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
In our special case the above is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(1)+2p(2)+\dots+7p(7)
&=\frac {6!}{7^6}
\left(
\frac1{0!}{7^0} +
\frac1{1!}{7^1} +
\frac1{2!}{7^2} +
\frac1{3!}{7^3} +
\frac1{4!}{7^4} +
\frac1{5!}{7^5} +
\frac1{6!}{7^6} 
\right)
\\
&=\frac{355081}{117649}
\approx 3.0181387007114\dots\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Because in the parenthesis the sum is a "special cut" of the exponential series, i am not expecting a closed formula.

---

Computer check:

```
sage: def p(k, F=7):
....:     return prod( [1,]+[1-j/F for j in [1..k-1]] ) * k/F
....: 
sage: def t(k, F=7):
....:     kk = F-k
....:     return factorial(kk) / F^kk
....: 
sage: t(1) * sum( [ 1/t(k) for k in [1..7] ] )
355081/117649
sage: sum( [ k*p(k) for k in [1..7] ] )
355081/117649
sage: sum( [   p(k) for k in [1..7] ] )
1
sage:
```

Some further check / experiment:

```
sage: F = 20
sage: sum( [ k*p(k, F) for k in [1..F] ] )
3387894135040576041/640000000000000000
sage: sum( [   p(k, F) for k in [1..F] ] )
1
sage: t(1, F) * sum( [ 1/t(k, F) for k in [1..F] ] )
3387894135040576041/640000000000000000
sage: _.n()
5.29358458600090
sage:
```

Comment: Your $p(n)$ is the [Ramanujan Q-function](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042793E0258N).